# Sharepoint 2010 Split screen

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I just need a general idea how is best to display a split screen. The split screen should be left hand side with tabs from different list where user can edit items and right side pdf file display.

[image: Like this image]

Actually there is Invoice list with data and invoice number is the primary key. There is another document library where pdf of the invoice is uploaded with the same primary key. There are also other list which has to shown in the tab format where primary key is invoice number.

For the user there will be Task with the URL where he can click and output screen open like the one shown above where he can edit the entry from different list.

I just want to know which would be an optimal solution. For example an application page which different tab as shown in the picture and on the right side pdf display but how to implement the Tab view in the application page ?.

Answer (score 2):

The part on the left could be customized New/Edit/View form for list item. Then create an invoice view (right part) as a web part. Then you can just define page layout in your custom item form and add web part with that invoice file. The pros of using web part are that you can reuse it anywhere on the site.

Use lookup fields to connect invoice properties and invoice file, if you do not want to store it all in document library.

Comment: Hallo Luccio, Thank you for your reply. Actually the user will have link to the custom application page with the invoice number so when the url is clicked. i have to fetch the data from the different list using the invoice number from the list url and display the edit options as in the picture..